# Integrate one visualisation from d3.js in an android application

Tags: javascript, android, d3.js

I want to develop an android application which is to integrate a visualization from d3.js. Is it possible? Can anyone explain how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

D3 is a library geared towards manipulating data and rendering it into an html DOM –– either via SVG, or straight up divs or perhaps a canvas. Of course there also needs to be a JavaScript engine that can run the code. Browsers provide all those things; native apps provide none of them out of the box.

However, there are ways to build native apps that wrap a javascript engine and DOM. [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) is a commonly used framework for doing so. It essentially lets you develop as if things are going to run in a browser, but they're packaged into a native app. There's a performance hit to that: It won't run as fast as a native app, and often not even as fast as the same code would run in a mobile browser. But from the user's perspective, it's installed and launched just like any native app.

That's AFAIK the only way to use d3 in a native app.